# Loading HTML from a remote URL securely in Electron

Tags: electron, electron-builder

I'm using Electron for a Desktop app, where installing and updating the app requires Administrator Privileges.
I've implemented the electron-builder's "auto update" functionality, but as most of the end users are not Administrators - new releases are reaching the users only when the IT personnel are available, which in my case could take a few days to a few weeks.

In general, the solution I'm going for is to build only the renderer into a single HTML file (that includes HTML, JS, CSS) and retrieve that file using `window.loadURL` from an AWS S3 bucket. This way I can update the renderer code just like updating a website.
This means I'll only be able to update the Renderer process, and not the Main process, but I'm fine with that for now.

My Electron app requires nodeIntegration to be active, and as per Electron's warning I should not use window.loadURL from a remote location, and nodeIntegration at the same time.

And so the direction I'm going for is a classic private-public key verification. In my Backend, I'll add a new API endpoint, which will fetch the HTML file from S3, sign it with a private key, pass the HTML content and the signature to the Electron app, and verify the signature matches the content (with the matching public key, which will be packaged with the Electron app).

I'd appreciate feedback regarding this approach, I'm mostly concerned about security implications. Also, if you have any other ideas about how to resolve such an issue (releasing updates while requiring Admin Privileges), I'd be happy to hear.

Sorry for the long post, I hope I'm in the right place for this kind of question, and thanks for reading :)

Comment: I think you shouldn't sign the file on the go. Rather, sign the file once you upload it to S3 and upload the signature file too. Then, your app downloads both files and verifies them against each other. This way, if your S3 bucket is compromised, your signature scheme is not affected as long as the private key is stored safely. Also, with cryptography it's best not to re-invent the wheel and I thus would use OpenPGP for this job.

Comment: Additionally, if you keep the auto-update functionality, it's also best to verify the public key bundled with the app against a trustworthy source (maybe publish a signed text file containing the single valid key fingerprint to S3?). Otherwise a malicious update could (in theory) circumvent all of this. Modifying Electron's ASAR files is pretty simple.

Comment: Thanks @AlexanderLeithner for the insightful response!You're 100% right about re-inventing the wheel. I like both ideas you mentioned, I'll definitely look into this.